# Change Data Type size on GetFileSize

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Using Delphi 7 to develop our main application. We are importing files of data. The filesize in bytes exceeds the size of the integer variable that vcl and my code use to hold it...so it goes negative and empty file actions are taken...

Our current code to check the filesize (and thereby decide if empty) is:

```
function getfilesize(vfilename: string): integer;
var
  SearchRec: TSearchRec;
begin
    try
    result:= -1;
    if FindFirst(vfilename, faAnyFile, SearchRec) = 0 then
      result:= SearchRec.Size;
    FindClose(SearchRec);
    except
      on e: exception do
        raise exception.create('Error: functions\getfilesize - Unable to analyze file Attributes to determine filesize. '#13#10+e.message);
    end;
```

Over the years this has changed back and forth, but for the last 5 years this has
worked well.

the searchrec.size is an INTEGER so just changing our return type
will not be sufficient. There are many other factors in store, related to our code and the database fields we use.

Q:   What other D7 methods of determining the filesize in bytes will work
     for us, which use a larger datatype?

Q:  Do you know of any other replacement functions to getFilesize in a larger integer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`GetFileAttributesEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364946%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is the most convenient Windows API to call. It's the fastest and unlike `GetFileSize()` does not require you to obtain a file handle.

Wrap it up like so:

```
function FileSize(const FileName: string): Int64; overload;
var
  AttributeData: TWin32FileAttributeData;
begin
  if not GetFileAttributesEx(PChar(FileName), GetFileExInfoStandard, @AttributeData) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  Int64Rec(Result).Lo := AttributeData.nFileSizeLow;
  Int64Rec(Result).Hi := AttributeData.nFileSizeHigh;
end;
```

If you happen to have a file handle then [`GetFileSizeEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364957%28VS.85%29.aspx) is probably best:

```
function GetFileSizeEx(hFile: THandle; var FileSize: Int64): BOOL; stdcall; external kernel32;

function FileSize(hFile: THandle): Int64; overload;
begin
  if not GetFileSizeEx(hFile, Result) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

Comment: +1 This is good. Sometimes you have a File Name but not a Handle, other times you have a Handle but not the File Name. ;)

Comment: @Craig When you have a handle it is trivial, you call [`GetFileSizeEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364957(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Is `windows.GetFileAttributesEx` any bad?

Comment: @Sertac Not there on D7 I suspect.

Comment: @David - Don't have D7 but it's there in D3.

Comment: @David Delphi 5 doesn't provide GetFileSizeEx, so I guess it's a toss-up whether I implement the external myself or use the more cumbersome version GetFileSize. :) Don't ask which OS's support which. :P That said, if you don't need the handle, then VERY NB: use one of the methods that don't need it (like this one).

Comment: @Craig It's trivial to produce your own import of GetFileSizeEx.

Answer (score 2):

try using the `FindData.nFileSizeHigh` and `FindData.nFileSizeLow`,  you can write something like this :

```
 function GetFileSizeExt(const FileName : TFileName) : Int64;
 var
   SearchRec : TSearchRec;
 begin
   if FindFirst(FileName, faAnyFile, SearchRec ) = 0 then
      result := Int64(SearchRec.FindData.nFileSizeHigh) shl Int64(32) + Int64(SearchRec.FindData.nFileSizeLow)
   else
      result := -1;

   FindClose(SearchRec) ;
 end;
```

Comment: +1 Shorter than mine (now that I made it work with D7), but expensive in that you have to create and destroy a SearchRec. Almost certainly irrelevant mind you.